# How can you compare "week-year" value in JS?

Tags: javascript, comparison, date-comparison

For example, I have the following `String` values in week-year format:

```
// week-year
"8-18" < "9-18"   // returns true
"8-18" < "10-18"  // returns false but should return true
"8-18" < "4-18"   // returns false but should be true
```

I have to sort out an array of arrays with "week-year" values for scheduling purposes. Currently I'm using `array.sort` to accomplish this:

```
var results = [
  [ 
    { weekyear:"4-18" } 
  ], 
  [
    { weekyear:"5-18" }
  ], 
  [
    { weekyear: "1-19" }
  ] ... ]

results.sort((function (index) { // Sort based on Week-Year in descending order 
  return function (a, b) {
    return (a[index].weekyear === b[index].weekyear ? 0 : (a[index].weekyear< b[index].weekyear ? -1 : 1));
  };
})(0));
```

Is there any way I can perhaps modify the `week-year` value into a numerical value that allows sorting?

The above sort should give me in order:

```
"1-19" , "5-18" , "4-18"
```

Comment: why would "8-18" < "4-18" return true?

Comment: "week 4 year 18" is earlier than "week 8 year 18". I guess I'm doing something wrong here, however I'd like to have a way to compare this value...

Comment: "8-18" < "9-18" is true and "8-18" < "4-18" should also be true? i dont understand how your comparing them

Comment: If you multiply the year by 100 and add the week, you can directly compare the numbers.

Comment: why are your objects in single arrays?

Comment: @NinaScholz Its just an example, my object is very large with one of the attributes as week-year :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a formatted string where the year comes first, followed by a padded week, which could be compared as string.

```js
function getYearWeek(weekYear) {
    return weekYear
        .split('-')
        .map(s => s.padStart(2, '0'))
        .reverse()
        .join('-W');
}

var results = [{ weekyear: "4-20" }, { weekyear: "5-18" }, { weekyear: "4-18" }, { weekyear: "1-19" }];

console.log(getYearWeek("8-18") < getYearWeek("9-18"));  // true
console.log(getYearWeek("8-18") < getYearWeek("10-18")); // true
console.log(getYearWeek("8-18") < getYearWeek("4-18"));  // false

results.sort((a, b) => 
    getYearWeek(a.weekyear).localeCompare(getYearWeek(b.weekyear)));

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```